# command line argument value checking and exiting the code

Tags: c

I am using the following code and I am trying to check the command line arguments value. if the user entered the wrong values it will print an error message and exit the program. However, this approach did not work with me and I am new in c programming. Is there another way to achieve this?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int a;  
    int b; 
    int c;
    

    if(argc != 4)
    {
        printf("Invalid usage of the file); 
        exit(0);
    }

    if ( ((atoi(argv[3])) != 1 || (atoi(argv[3]))) != 0 && (atoi(argv[1])) < 0 && (atoi(argv[2])) < 0 ) {
        printf("Invalid arguments\n"); 
        exit(0);
    }

    a = atoi(argv[1]);
    b = atoi(argv[2]);
    c = atoi(argv[3]); 
}
```

When I run the file, I am expecting that the user can only enter positive numbers for argv[1] and argv[2], and for argv[3] he can only enter 0 or 1. for example:

```
./filename 5 5 1
```

Comment: Instructions ae executed sequencially. You need to check if `argc` is != 4 __before__ dereferencing `argv[n]`.

Comment: Also show some example of input and expected vs. actual output.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Thanks. I actually tried what you have suggested but sadly I am still not able to achieve my goal. I edited the code

Comment: Error messages belong on stderr.  If the program fails due to an invalid call, it should exit nonzero.  eg fprintf(stderr, "error msg"); exit(1);

Comment: Are you building an executable or attempting to execute your source code?

Comment: @WilliamPursell, this is was helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is overly complicated and the condition is wrong.

You want this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  if (argc != 4)  // check argument count
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Invalid usage of the file"); // rather print to stderr
    exit(1);                                      // use exit(1) in case of error
  }

  // retrieve arguments
  int a = atoi(argv[1]);
  int b = atoi(argv[2]);
  int c = atoi(argv[3]);

  // check validity of arguments
  if (a < 0 || b < 0 || (c != 0 && c != 1)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Invalid arguments\n");  // rather print to stderr
    exit(1);                                 // use exit(1) in case of error
  }
}
```

The parentheses around `(c != 0 && c != 1)` are redundant, it's just for better redability.

`(a < 0 || b < 0 || (c != 0 && c != 1)` in plain English:
*a is smaller than 0 or b is smaller than zero or c is different from 0 and different from 1*.

Comment: This is was helpful. Thanks! I am just wondering if I typed a character value instead of 0 or 1 for the argv[3] it works as the case if I typed zero, do you have an idea why this is happening?

Comment: @seraabrj no need for thank you comments, they only add noise. Accepting the answer is good enough.